# CodeBlocks error with Strings and Structures

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ide, structure, codeblocks

This is a header file in C++ that I've made on Codeblocks. On compile time the IDE gives me an error saying:  `'FailureToFindScriptFileError' does not name a type`
I've cross-checked sources on the internet about how structures are supposed to be implemented but I can't seem to find the problem. Moreover, when i typed down the same code in a main file, it ran without any problem. Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

```
#ifndef SCRIPT_H_INCLUDED
#define SCRIPT_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
struct ErrorId
{
    char* numberID;
    char* quote;
};

ErrorId FailureToFindScriptFileError;

FailureToFindScriptFileError.numberID = "0001";
FailureToFindScriptFileError.quote = "Script File could not be found.";

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two instructions (i.e. two assignments) outside of a function. You have to initialize the structure when it is declared:

```
ErrorId FailureToFindScriptFileError = { "0001", "Script File could not be found." };
```

Another option is to move the assignments into the `main` function for example.